# Protractor - if element is displayed, click on it doesn't work with by.buttonText

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have switched from finding an element by id to by.buttonText due to the fact I now use a single button with variable text. My test have started to fail.

This is my button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.watchUnwatchDriver()">{{vm.model.isWatched ? 'Un-' : ''}}Watch Driver</button>
```

This evaluates to either 'Watch Driver' or 'Un-Watch Driver' based on `vm.model.isWatched`.

Initially I set my button to be Watch Driver so that I test if the Un-Watch button isDisplayed and potentially click on it if it is.

I have started to see this message

> Failed: No element found using locator: by.buttonText("Un-Watch Driver")✗

My test looks like so

```
describe('Watch/Un-Watch Driver Test', function() {

    var watchBtn = element(by.buttonText('Watch Driver'));
    var unwatchBtn = element(by.buttonText('Un-Watch Driver'));

    it('should set Driver watch status to default: un-watched', function() {

        unwatchBtn.isDisplayed().then(function(visible) {
            if (visible) {
                unwatchBtn.click();
            }
        });

        expect(unwatchBtn.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
    });

    it('should watch a driver', function() {
        watchBtn.click();
        expect(unwatchBtn.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should un-watch a driver', function() {
        unwatchBtn.click();
        expect(unwatchBtn.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isPresent() seems to work okay for me. It successfully detects if button with such name is present.

```
it('should set Driver watch status to default: un-watched', function() {

    unwatchBtn.isPresent().then(function(visible) {
        if (visible) {
            unwatchBtn.click();
            expect(unwatchBtn.isPresent()).toBe(false);
        } else {
            expect(unwatchBtn.isPresent()).toBe(false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print your button text and observe for example:

```
var unwatchBtn = element(by.css('.btn.btn-primary'));

unwatchBtn.getText().then(function(text){
console.log(text);
})
```

then use that text in by.buttonText

Comment: Smart but I've got more than button with that class.

Comment: use a specific locater like:

Answer (score 0):

You can try `element(by.partialButtonText('Watch Driver'))` and it will work in both cases.